# Alpine with hotmail | SMTP | cannot send email

Tags: email, smtp, alpine-linux

Dear Unix and Linux Community,

I would like to use my hotmail account through alpine. I am using the POP3 protocol, and I am able to access the email from my Inbox.

However, I am unable to send any email directly through alpine. Upon trying to send an email, I obtain the following message:

```
   [Sending mail |      100%    |]
   [Mail not sent. Sending error: 250 2.0.0 Resetting]
```

I am currently accessing the following SMTP server:

```
    smtp-mail.outlook.com:587/pop3/user=myemail@hotmail.com
```

I have also tried port 25 to no avail. Occasionally it gets stuck, displaying the following:

```
    [Sending mail |      0%    |]
```

Using the TLS encryption explicitly gives the same error message:

```
    smtp-mail.outlook.com:587/user=myemail@hotmail.com/tls
```

since TLS is implemented by default.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Sending error: 250` means authentication error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the customized headers field or it won't work.
quoting from [Alpine Faq](https://www.washington.edu/alpine/faq/config.html#6.5):

> From Alpine's [M]AIN MENU, choose [S]etup, then [C]onfig. Move down to
>   the Customized Headers option. Press "A Add Value". Use the format:
>
> ```
>     From: "My Real Name" <myusername@hotmail.com>
> ```

although i used the key C ( means change values ) to change the value and W ( where is ) to find customized headers faster.

Comment: I forgot to add that I had already tried that one. Using `smtp-mail.outlook.com:587/user=myemail@hotmail.com/tls` gives the same error message as stated in the question. According to [this] (https://www.washington.edu/alpine/tech-notes/config-notes.html), the tls encryption is used by default. By adding it explicitly ones just makes sure that in the case the communication fails no insecure connection is tried.

Comment: i think it's better to edit your question and add that.

Comment: Done. Do you have any other idea on what could cause the problem?

Comment: yes i have, i did it. i'm editing the answer right now.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your time. Do you know what was Alpine doing? I thought the user=myemail@hotmail.com string in the SMTP server specification was enough.

Comment: can you upvote the answer too?

Comment: I can't. I still do not have enough reputation. The vote is recorded but it does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

I got "Mail not sent. Sending error: 250" from the alpine e-mail program today.  After much ado, I discovered that one of the lines of the e-mail (composed with linux's visual editor vi) exceeded an e-mail line-length limit (1000 characters or so).  I broke the line in half, and the e-mail went just fine.